# How to setup profile in launchSettings.json in Unit Test project (unit test runs but does not debug)

Tags: unit-testing, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I've created a new Unit Test project using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` for .net on Windows, configured as

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

......
</Project>
```

When I run any `TestMethod` It wouldn't hit breakpoints, and test behaves as `Run` instead of `Debug`. When I comment out profile in launchSettings.json, now I can hit breakpoints and debug.

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    //"WSL": {
    //  "commandName": "WSL2",
    //  "distributionName": ""
    //}
  }
}
```

Question: why VS does this out of the box, and how I can benefit from potential settings in launchSettings.json?